# Dockerized NextJS breaks router

Tags: reactjs, docker, next.js, router

I got NextJS app which works quite fine with `yarn dev`.
Now I've put it into Docker (**docker-compose** with **Dockerfile** etc.)

If I run the app from exposed port (`localhost:3000`), it serves `/app/app/*.tsx` instead of just the public part in `/app/*.tsx. The` /app/app/` is private route, so it redirects to login.

Then it breaks cos Next doesn't recognize /user/login page, so it serves /app/app, redirects again and again...

Directory structure is:

```bash
app
├── app
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   ├── layout.tsx
│   ├── _menuItem.ts
│   ├── page.tsx
│   ├── settings
│   │   └── page.tsx
├── layout.tsx
├── page.tsx
└── user
    ├── layout.tsx
    ├── login
    │   └── page.tsx
    └── register
        └── page.tsx
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:18-alpine AS development

VOLUME /app/

WORKDIR /app/

COPY ./frontend-next/package.json ./frontend-next/yarn.lock /app/

# Check https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine to understand why libc6-compat might be needed.
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat tzdata git
RUN yarn config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org && \
    yarn global add next react && yarn install --force

ENV TZ=Europe/Prague

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["yarn", "dev"]
```

```yaml
  nextapp:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./docker/nextjs/Dockerfile
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      # loaded from .env file
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - ./frontend-next/:/app:rw
```